# C# not allowing duplicate dates in list & combobox

Tags: c#, list, combobox, duplicates

My assignment program has a calendar that a user chooses dates from, and then these dates are added to a combo box, and a list. It should not allow duplicates, but I can't seem to catch them.

After adding dates, the user has a button that will show the available dates from the combo box in a list/array in a text box. Am I incorrect in initializing the list with the combo box? Is there a different way to catch date duplicates in a combo box and list?

```
    private void desktopDateTime_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            bool isDuplicate = false;
            List<DateTime> availableDates = new List<DateTime>();

            foreach(DateTime date in availableDates)
            {
                if(date == desktopDateTime.Value)
                {
                    isDuplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isDuplicate == false)
            {
                availableDates.Add(desktopDateTime.Value);
                availableComboBox.Items.Add(desktopDateTime.Value.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                isDuplicate = false;
                MessageBox.Show("No duplicate dates allowed");
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list `availableDates` is defined in the scope of your method. Meaning that each time `desktopDateTime_ValueChanged` is called a new (empty) list is created.

You'll need to put the list in the scope of your class, instead of the method. That will allow multiple calls to `desktopDateTime_ValueChanged` to use the same list, instead of different ones. So something like:

```
private List<DateTime> availableDates = new List<DateTime>();

private void desktopDateTime_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isDuplicate = false;

        foreach(DateTime date in availableDates)
        //  ...
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was misunderstanding, Moving it out now triggers the duplicate message box.